# Why is my proximity prompt not showing up

Tags: roblox

I have been trying to make a proximity prompt on a Zombie model in Roblox but it won't show up, no matter where i put it. Here is the explorer:
 [image]

Can someone help me fix this issue? (Also I have tried putting it in a part, but the follow script doesn't move the part)